# How to get a count of splits in an image

Tags: python, recursion, image-processing

I'm new to image processing and having hard time adjusting to it. I'm basically trying to write a recursive function to get the count of how many splits there are of an image. if you were to cut the entire image into four equal squares, and each square contained at least one black pixel, then index 0 of level_count would be four. If only three of the four squares contained at least one black pixel, then index 0 would be three. I However, I don't know where to start it from. It is a part of a school assignment but teachers and TA's are no help. If anyone can help it will be a big help.

```
def split_into_four(im, level, level_count):
    num_level = (round(math.log2(float(im.shape[0])/4)))
    level_count= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am lucky to know this question because I just teach a student and guide his homework. Here are code:

```
def split_into_four(im, level):

        if level ==1:
            if contains_pixel(im):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0

        if im.shape >(4,4) :
            return (split_into_four(im[:int(len(im)/2),:int(len(im)/2)],int(level/2))+
            split_into_four(im[:int(len(im)/2),int(len(im)/2):],int(level/2))+
            split_into_four(im[int(len(im)/2):,int(len(im)/2):],int(level/2))+
            split_into_four(im[int(len(im)/2):,:int(len(im)/2)],int(level/2))
            )
```

**Just like this and I delete an parameter because I don't konw why I need to use it**

```
FileName = input('please input the filename :')
im = open_image(FileName)
num_level = (round(math.log2(float(im.shape[0])/4)))
list = num_level * [0]
list1 = [int(math.pow(2,i)) for i in range(1,len(list)+1)]
list2=[split_into_four(im,i) for i in list1]
print(list2)
print(list1)
print(plot_line_fit([math.log(i) for i in list1], [math.log(i) for i in list2]))
```